# Why is my find and xargs copy command working for one folder and not for the other?

Tags: bash, unix, find, xargs

I have two directories, `x86_64` and `i386`.
I want to filter out test RPMS from both of these folders and place them in a seperate one; `test_release/{version}-x86_64/x86_64` and `test_release/{version}-i386/i386`, respectively.

So my first command works fine:

```
find x86_64/ -type f -name '*test*' -o -name '*demo*' -o -name '*log*' |
xargs cp -rt test_release/${RELEASE}-x86_64/x86_64
```

My second command is exactly the same, except with different folder names:

```
find i386/ -type f -name '*test*' -o -name '*demo*' -o -name '*log*' |
xargs cp -rt test_release/${RELEASE}-i386/i386
```

Only the second command gives me the error:

```
cp: missing file operand
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Might not be related but your find command will select **folders** matching `*demo*` or `*log*` as well as **files**

Comment: Does `find` in the second command gives you an output if you run it alone i.e. without xargs ?

Comment: @Pacifist no, it does not give me an output. Apparently it cannot find the folder i386? It does give me output when I do the same for the x86 folder.

Comment: @oguzismail I thought by specifying the -type f flag it would only give me files?

Comment: That's the problem right there. `cp <source> <target>` , it is missing source. Same is working for the first command as the source is not missing there.

Comment: @Pacifist But both commands are identical. The source for the first one is x86_64/ and for the second one it's i386/. I don't understand how it cannot 'find' the folder (being its source) in the second command.

Comment: @Mirwais Does it give you any errors? Folder with name i386 exists?

Comment: @Pacifist I found my mistake. The contect of the i386 folder does not contain files with "test" or "demo" in it. However it does contain "Tst" and "Demo". I need to build something around this. Thank you for thinking alongside with me for a solution!

Comment: @Mirwais for Demo you can use `-iname` , with `i` it ignores the case.

Comment: Wrt *I thought by specifying the -type f flag it would only give me files*, not always. You should do it like `find x86_64/ -type f \( -name '*test*' -o -name '*demo*' -o -name '*log*' \)`

Comment: If `find` does not find anything, then `xargs` will still try to execute `cp` nonetheless without any arguments. Have a look at the `-r` option of `xargs`. Also, it is better to use `find … -print0` and `xargs -0 …` to avoid problems with white-spaces in filenames.

Comment: @Robin479 find has `-exec`, xargs is unnecessary here. and `-print0` is a GNU extension, it's not a standard option

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because your `find` command doesn't return any files. Disappointingly, `xargs` still runs `cp`, but ends up calling it with too few arguments; and so you get the error message.

GNU `xargs` has an `-r` option which solves this specific case; but a more portable and more robust solution is to use `find -exec`.

```
find i386/ -type f -name '*test*' -o -name '*demo*' -o -name '*log*' \
    -exec cp -rt "test_release/${RELEASE}-i386/i386" {} +
```

The `+` statement terminator for `-exec` is not entirely portable, but if you have `cp -t` I guess you're on Linux, or at least are using a recent `find` (GNU or not GNU. If not, replacing `+` with `\;` is a workaround, though it will end up running more processes than the equivalent `xargs` construct).